# How to create this type of menu and all structure

Tags: html, css

I want to create this type of template like menu and all stuff so please can any one suggest me how to create.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a navbar on top of your page. Then you have to edit that navbar on every separate page, so that it shows an image behind the hyperlink of the page you are on. That image should be that white "highlight". In that way people can see very easy what page they are on. So it would look something like this:

html:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="about.html" class='active'>About-us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Solutions.html">Solutions</a></li>
    <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you should do something like this:

```
.navbar ul li a.active
{
background-image: url(your image url for the page you are on);
}
```

You should move the class of your hyperlink on the other pages, to the list item of the page you are currently on.